# border-radius doesn't quite touch div contents

Tags: html, css

So I have a rounded corner'd div created via the CSS3 "border-radius" rule. It has a child element at the top that has a background color (in this case, the same color as the border color). It's almost perfectly fine, except for the fact that they don't *quite* touch each other in the corner. It's visible at normal zoom, but much easier to see zoomed in:

[image: not quite touching]

(This screenshot was taken in the latest version of Google Chrome, but I observe the same problem in Firefox)

As a complicating factor, sometimes the .title_bar element is a table-row. How do I make that tiny gap go away?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="round_box">
    <div class="title_bar">Hello</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.round_box {
    border: 2px solid #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.round_box .title_bar {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ya9wU/)

Comment: You could use a slightly bigger border-radius on the parent div, which is laying underneath.

Comment: Is it possible to show the code? +1 for a good clear question.

Comment: @kleinfreund there is no border radius on the child div. Gimme a minute and I'll post some code...

Comment: @kleinfreund: I just tried removing the "overflow: hidden" and giving a slightly smaller border-radius to .title_bar. It works great when title_bar is a div, but sometimes title_bar is a `tr`, which can't take border-radii

Comment: @Mala: I've got it wrong in the first place – but I meant to work with two border-radius values on the two elements. You still could use border-radius on td-elements and only apply them to specific ones.

Comment: @kleinfreund that's a great idea... I could use first-child and last-child to do that, right?

Comment: other option would be to lay hover a pseudo-element 1px bigger or smaller. GOOD Question anyway !

Comment: @Mala: That's exactly what I've meant. (other than that: I believe you  safely can omit the prefixes – http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)

Comment: @kleinfreund if I omit the prefixes wouldn't it apply to all of the tds, essentially giving me a weird bumpy titlebar?

Comment: @Mala: I mean the vendor prefixes like -moz, -webkit and so on.

Comment: oh right, thanks. Could you please submit your solution as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: I did. Also please clarify in your question you also need rounded corners on table row elements sometimes.

Comment: @kleinfreund I actually ended up going with the setting the bg color, since it turns out I need the overflow:hidden so that the bottom of the box works right. But thanks so much for the help, and for teaching me a thing or two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add/move the `background-color`  to .round_box

http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/fHECx

```
.round_box {
    border: 2px solid #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #333;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does get rid of the gap, but I would need to change the markup somewhat unpleasantly in order to use this, as I'd need to wrap everything outside of title_bar in a div that I could make white again. Still, +1 for an answer that may help someone else :)

Comment: actually with a `.round_box > * {color: #fff}` I can make this work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: can't edit the comment anymore, but by `color` I meant `background`

Answer (score 3):

You can resolve this by removing the border, since you have a black border on a black background you can't see where one starts and the other ends!

```
.round_box {
   /*  border: 2px solid #333;  REMOVE THIS */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.round_box .title_bar {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

[Working version](http://jsfiddle.net/cHLpG/)

Comment: err... but then I don't have the border

Comment: But it will still have rounded edges.

Comment: @Mala Yes, but you have a black border on a black background  - you can't see the border!

Comment: it works in that the gap is gone, but it doesn't in that the "round_box" is no longer a round box but an invisible box with a rounded bar on top (unless I'm misunderstanding something?)

Comment: @Mala, did you click the link I gave?

Comment: @DaveRook: yes... but only on the title_bar part. The rest of the box is white (or whatever color is behind it) - yes i clicked it. Sorry my question may not have been clear, I left some of the details to be inferred from the code: the title_bar is a thing that goes above the rest of the content, which isn't in a grey background

Answer (score 1):

*(Note: The author of the question needs rounded corners on the parent and child div - plus sometimes the child is a table row.)*

(possible) Solution: Use border-radius on both the parent and the child. If the child is a tr – apply it to the first and last td-elements with `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="round_box">
    <div class="title_bar">Hello</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.round_box {
    border: 2px solid #333;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.round_box .title_bar {
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #fff;
}

.round_box td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}

.round_box td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: This works a charm, and would be my preferred solution were it not for another factor that I did not specify in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

without overflow:hide 
use LEFT and Top also height equal to parent

```
  min-height: 52px;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 0.5px;
```

also  radius for both child and parent

```
  border-radius: 26px 26px 26px 26px;
  border-radius: 0px 26px 26px 0px;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzWu0.png)